# value setInterval does not match

Tags: angular, typescript, setinterval

I have a sentence getter function that I want to put into setInterval with the value returned but the value returned is not clear

```
       //RandomTeks
        let getTeks = () =>{
          this.idNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.idRandom) + 1;
          this.kalimat = resp[this.idNumber].kalimat
          this.kalimatGlobal = this.kalimat

         return this.kalimatGlobal //sentence content
        }

        //Interval
        this.intervalValue = setInterval(() => {
            return getTeks()
        }, 500);

        console.log(this.intervalValue)//return value is 9 or 10
```

> I was wondering why the return value of a variable whose contents are setInterval is number 9 or number 10? does anyone know why?

**any help, advice, or whatever it is I really appreciate it**

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` as well as `setTimeout` returns a number which is timer ID. You can then use it to cancel your interval or timeout:

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('Interval')
}, 1000) // Set interval that runs every second

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(interval)
}, 10000) // And stop it after 10 seconds
```

It doesn't return any value. And which value do you expect it to return? Consider this code

```
console.log('Before interval')

const value = setInterval(() => {
  return "Inside interval"
}, 1000)

console.log('After interval')
```

This actually prints

```
Before interval
After interval
Inside interval
Inside interval
Inside interval
...
```

This is because when you call `setInterval` your code doesn't stop execution, it continues on, reaches `console.log('After interval')` and only after a second runs your function inside interval. So right after you called `setInterval` your function hasn't been called, so there is no value to assign to `value` or `intervalValue` in your example.

So how to solve it depends on how you are gonna use it. You could get tasks inside interval and use them there as well:

```
function handleSomething(teks) {
  // do something with teks
}

setInterval(() => {
  const teks = getTeks()
  handleSomething(teks)
}, 500);
```

Or you could make a mutable variable and assign values to it periodically

```
let intervalValue = null

setInterval(() => {
  intervalValue = getTeks()
}, 500)
```

Or maybe you could use Promises, it really depends